# Making an ArrayAdapter<ItemCategory> accept LinkedHashSet instead of ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my app Im using a LinkhedHashSet instead of an ArrayList to hold ItemCategory objects (POJOs with name and id properties)
Now I want to load this LinkedHashSet in a Spinned without having to convert the LinkedHashsSet to an ArrayList beforehand. Is it possible? Here is my code

```
public static void loadSpinnerData(Context context, ArrayList<ItemCategory> array, Spinner spinner) {

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<ItemCategory> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemCategory>(context,
            R.drawable.simple_spinner_item, array);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

}

btw I've overriden the toString() method in ItemCategory object to return the category name:

```
public class ItemCategory {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an `ArrayAdapter`. Instead, extend from [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). You'll have to duplicate some of the behavior of `ArrayAdapter`, but you won't be hampered by its restrictions.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/) details some adapter good practices.

Answer (score 1):

extend your adapter by `BaseAdapter` and override `getCount` method by returning size of `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no you can't. If you look at the [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) API reference, you'll see that you can only give it an array or a list of entries.